# customize \label and \ref

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

This must be easy, but my TeX knowledge is insufficient.

How can I make `\label{key}` in an enumerate environment reference the item's `enumi` instead of the item's `\theenumi` (which seems to be the default).

Problem: I have used `\renewcommand\theenumi{\footnotesize{\emph{Element~\arabic{enumi}}}}`, and therefore `\ref{key}` (eg. in the third item) returns "Element 3" and not simply "3"---which is what I am looking for.

Will be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: while using enumitem package as in the answer below is probably easier the problem is that your definition is incorrect. you should have left `\theenumi` unchanged and redefined `\labelenumi` which is what is used for the item label.

Comment: I think he changed the value of `\theenumi` because he wanted to change the way the items were numbered, and `\labelenumi` by default expands to `\theenumi`, so he got both. But you have a good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a breeze with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) as it allows you to specify separate `label` and `ref`erence keys for your lists:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\footnotesize\emph{Element~\arabic*}},ref=\arabic*]
  \item First item\label{item1}
  \item[(b)] Second item
  \item Third item\label{item3}
\end{enumerate}

This should be one: \ref{item1}

This should be two: \ref{item3}

\end{document}
```

A special `*`-form is used to identify the actual counter formatting.

Answer (score 1):

By doing some `\show`'s, you can see that `\label` uses the command `\@currentlabel` to determine what the reference should be. So using `etoolbox`, we can say:

```
\newif\if@mynoitemarg
\@mynoitemargfalse
\def\item{\@inmatherr\item\@ifnextchar[%
    \@item
    {\@noitemargtrue\@mynoitemargtrue\@item[\@itemlabel]}%
}%]
\apptocmd\@item{
    \xdef\@currentlabel{\if@mynoitemarg\arabic{enumi}\else #1\fi}
    \if@mynoitemarg\@mynoitemargfalse\fi\ignorespaces
}
```

and it will behave in the way you want.

Here's a complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@mynoitemarg
\@mynoitemargfalse
\def\item{\@inmatherr\item\@ifnextchar[%
    \@item
    {\@noitemargtrue\@mynoitemargtrue\@item[\@itemlabel]}%
}%]
\apptocmd\@item{
    \xdef\@currentlabel{\if@mynoitemarg\arabic{enumi}\else #1\fi}
    \if@mynoitemarg\@mynoitemargfalse\fi\ignorespaces
}
\makeatother
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item this \label{a}
\item[hi]  \label{hi}
\item again  \label{b}
\item[there] \label{there}

\end{enumerate}

This should be one: \ref{a}

This should be two: \ref{b}

This should be hi: \ref{hi}

This should be there: \ref{there}
\end{document}
```

Edit: Werner pointed out that my previous solution didn't work with optional arguments to \item, so I fixed that and defined the label text in that situation to be the optional argument provided.

Comment: Your approach would fail if the user specifies an optional argument for `\item`.