# Perform math operation with values of \labels

Tags: cross-referencing, calculations

I use `\label` to index the number of items in several environments. I wish to perform the sum of the quantities reported by those labels. Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Control enumerate's layout

\newenvironment{myenumerate}{
   \begin{enumerate}[label={\footnotesize\emph{item~\arabic*}},ref=\arabic*] % this is how enumitem lets you set different label and ref, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286879/customize-label-and-ref
   \setlength{\itemsep}{.1\itemsep}
   \setlength{\parskip}{.1\parskip}
}{\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

First environmnent:
\begin{myenumerate}
\item A
\item B
\item C \label{nitems1st}
\end{myenumerate}

Second environmnent:
\begin{myenumerate}
\item D
\item E \label{nitems2nd}
\end{myenumerate}

There are \ref{nitems1st} items in the first and \ref{nitems2nd} in the second. How can I compute the sum?

\end{document}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can added numerical references using a combination of LaTeX3 `\calc` and [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Control enumerate's layout
\usepackage{xparse,refcount}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{label={\footnotesize\emph{item~\arabic*}},ref=\arabic*}

\begin{document}

First environmnent:
\begin{myenumerate}
  \item A
  \item B
  \item C \label{nitems1st}
\end{myenumerate}

Second environmnent:
\begin{myenumerate}
  \item D
  \item E \label{nitems2nd}
\end{myenumerate}

There are \ref{nitems1st} items in the first and \ref{nitems2nd} in the second.

There are a total of \calc{\getrefnumber{nitems1st}+\getrefnumber{nitems2nd}} items.

\end{document}
```

---

If your reference to the total is always *after* all enumerations, then you can use [`xassoccnt`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xassoccnt) to count every step of the list environment items:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Control enumerate's layout
\usepackage{xassoccnt}

\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myenumerate]{label={\footnotesize\emph{item~\arabic*}},ref=\arabic*}

\DeclareAssociatedCounters[autodefine=associated]{myenumeratei}{totalmyenum}

\begin{document}

First environmnent:
\begin{myenumerate}
  \item A
  \item B
  \item C \label{nitems1st}
\end{myenumerate}

Second environmnent:
\begin{myenumerate}
  \item D
  \item E \label{nitems2nd}
\end{myenumerate}

There are \ref{nitems1st} items in the first and \ref{nitems2nd} in the second.

There are a total of \thetotalmyenum{} items.

\end{document}
```

Comment: +0.5 for the general answer and +0.5  for using `xassoccnt` ;-) -- `xassoccnt` emulates some features `totcount` package, it's possible to know the total sum of enumerate items (per level only, of course) in advance after two compilations.